# How to enable User Authentication in MLFLOW?

Tags: databricks, open-source, mlflow, artifacts

I'm trying to enable MLFLOW user based authentication in Local Linux server using python

Able to start the server the mlflow server with the following command :

**mlflow server --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db --default-artifact-root ./artifacts --host 0.0.0.0**

But wasn't able to find any kind of authentication setup available when starting a server

Expectation:

Need a server web interface with Username and Password based authentication

Suggestions and Appropriate solutions are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mlflow's basic authentication: Provide a `basic_auth.ini` file similar to this

```
[mlflow]
default_permission = READ
database_uri = sqlite:///basic_auth.db
admin_username = admin
admin_password = SuperSecurePassword
```

and add `--app-name basic-auth` to mlflow

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db --default-artifact-root ./artifacts --host 0.0.0.0 --app-name basic-auth
```

`basic_auth.ini` needs to be in `mlflow/server/auth/` under the site-packages directory, so for example `/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mlflow/server/auth/basic_auth.ini`

You can find the correct site-packages directory with `python -c 'import mlflow;print(mlflow.__path__)'`